# Howto map entity by paramconverter by parent class

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine, abstract-class

I have a parent class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Blog;

/**
 * Class Tag
 * This is the parent class for all Tags
 */
abstract class Tag
{
    /**
      @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag_name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $tagName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $slug;
    // ... getters and setters
```

and 2 child classes:
OtherTag

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Blog;

/**
 * OtherTag 
 * @ORM\Table(name="othertag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Blog\OtherTagRepository")
 */
class OtherTag extends Tag
```

and JobTag

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Blog;

/**
 * JobTag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="jobtag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Blog\JobTagRepository")
 */
class JobTag extends Tag
```

In my controller, I want to map the tags by tagnames or by slugs, but I can't get it to work. I don't want to write every action (like add user to tag subscription or delete user subscription) twice, so I thought, it would work like this:

```
/**
 * Add user subscription to tag.
 * @Route("/subscription/add/{tagname}", name="subscription_add_tag")
 * @ParamConverter("tag", options={"mapping":{"tagname":"tagName"}})
 */
public function addUserTagAction(Tag $tag)
{
    //TODO: some code to add user
}
```

But I get the error:

> Controller
>   "AppBundle\Controller\Blog\TagController::addUserTagAction()" requires
>   that you provide a value for the "$tag" argument. Either the argument
>   is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has
>   been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one.

How can I map the child entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your [own custom ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter)

```
namespace Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

interface ParamConverterInterface
{
    function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration);

    function supports(ParamConverter $configuration);
}
```

Then you declare it as a service and use it like

@ParamConverter("tagname", class="AcmeBundle:Tag", converter="your_service_name")

Comment: For those who find this via search, consider these pages also:
[stfalcon.com](https://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/symfony2-custom-paramconverter)
[blog.ebene7.com](http://blog.ebene7.com/2013/01/31/symfony2-custom-paramconverter-fuer-http-requests-erstellen/)
[gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/jperovic/24d3b1778bc86429c7b3)
These pages show some examples who to use it!